How do I flatten/reduce the depth of a local copy of git?
I'm currently playing around ladybird. The 'workflow' for running it right now is to pull a current build from git, then running a script that compiles and runs it. I'm not a dev so I don't really 'need' the full git history locally - I just need the 'latest' build. While there's probably alternative ways to do this (download the zip file off the github repo and delete the old ones? - would mean recompiling each time though), how would/could I flatten my local copy to a specified depth to save space, in the same manner as "git clone --depth" but on an existing copy that's already downloaded?

qq, when you talk about the zip file, does the zip file contain the repo, or does the repo contain the zip file?

The former - I could probably just wget the zip file off GitHub, unzip it over my build folder and go from there. Deleting fully means a full recompile which takes longer and I am running this on a VM on a lowish end machine for now. In theory I could just throw more storage at the problem but it's an uglier solution than git witchcraft or replacing the files

More or less I'm using it as an 'easy' way to get an updated copy of the main/trunk branch. Their build system is smart enough to only rebuild the stuff that's changed.  The 'smart' solution would be to rebuild with more than the bare minimal space but I feel like there should be a way to go from a full repo to a shallow one, if you can go the other way

so your desired state would be to pull the main branch periodically to get the updates? and you never push code, right? if so, you may be able to squash all the commits after the head (do not modify the head commit or you won't be able to pull) into a single commit. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9725156/remove-old-git-commits . Modifying server-side history in git is dangerous, so most of its features assume that if client and server have differing histories, that the differences are on the head end, and that the client will have more complex history than the server.

I'll never push code - I just want to test various things out with the latest release at the time I'm running it. So very much that, and not recompile anything that's not changed.

I pull the code, and there's a script that pulls some prerequisites, and compiles it. I'm trying to avoid adding more storage (I have some ideas there) + there's some other situations in the past I've had to handle where this would be useful

Sorry I can't be of more help. removing old commits from local git history just isn't a thing unless you rewrite the history, or clone it new with the depth argument. since the build creates new untracked files within the repo's directory, perhaps you can back them up prior to re-cloning.
